# Running a chainlink node on GCP, when connecting to the DB I get [ERROR] unable to lock ORM: dial tcp?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, ssh, chainlink

I`m running a chainlink node on GCP ,I followed the chainlink docs https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/, I created my VM and a DB , SSH tunneled through Google cloud SDK, but when trying to connect to my DB with cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.9.8 local n I get:

[image]

So I tried to use psql client to connect to the instance with psql -h [address IP]  -U [db_user], but got

```
Is the server running on host "35.100....16" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So after that, I tried to manually open the port 5432 in GCP but still nothing... If I run netstat -na I get this:

[image]

I also double-checked my .env if the DATABASE_URL is correct.

Managed to find some similar errors on Stack, but nothing has helped so far.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue with setting up a private IP connection instead of public one for my SQL database and changed my .env file.

Comment: Nice! Can you please approve this question?

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the scenario using the [Running a Chainlink Node](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/)
 and [How to build a simple Chainlink node on the GCP](https://medium.com/alpha-vantage/how-to-build-a-simple-chainlink-node-on-the-gcp-62df9e7801a2)  and I was able to start the Chainlink Node.
The issue is with the network path for connecting to the PostgreSQL DB instance; it is “Public IP” and without any "Authorized networks" by default when creating the DB. On using the Public IP address to connect the Chainlink node with the DB, I faced the same error.
This can be resolved by following either of the two methods:

1. If the network path for connecting to the PostgreSQL DB instance is “Public IP”, then add the VM’s(Node) External IP to “Authorized networks” in PostgreSQL DB instance details. [Configure access to your Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql) for more information.
2. Change the network path for connecting to the PostgreSQL DB instance to “Private IP” with “default” network and use the Private IP Address of the PostgreSQL DB instance when connecting the Node.